# Magento 2 Soap API issue

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, magento2

I'm pretty much a beginner, and switched to Magento 2 since 1 month, i've started coding a module for a third party application integration.

I've put down some code but i cant figure out how to make a soap call to my Function:
There's the code:

"etc/di.xml"

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\PriceServiceInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\PriceService" />
```

"etc/webapi.xml"

```
<route url="/V1/Vendor/PriceChange" method="POST">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\PriceServiceInterface" method="PriceChange"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

"Api/PriceServiceInterface"

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

interface PriceServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * GET for Post api
     * @param string $name
     * @return string
     */

    public function PriceChange($name);
}
```

"Model/PriceService.php"

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
use Vendor\Module\Api\PriceServiceInterface;

class PriceService implements PriceServiceInterface
{
    public function PriceChange($name) {
        return json_encode("Hello, " . $name);
    }
}
```

When i call: https://magento/soap/all?wsdl_list=1 with PostMan the call is present:

```
"vendorModulePriceServiceV1": {
        "wsdl_endpoint": "https://magento/admin/soap/all?wsdl&services=vendorModulePriceServiceV1"
    },
```

if i call the ENdPoint https://magento/it/soap/it?wsdl&services=vendorModulePriceServiceV1
there's a list of xml.

At this point i dont know what should i call to pass parameters by XML and process the function.

i've tryed with: https://Magnto/soap/it/V1/vendor/PriceChange
But inside the XML Body i dont know what should i declare, so it ends up giving me the following error:

```
Incorrect format of request URI or Requested services are missing
```

the xml built:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:def="https://magento/soap/default?services=vendorModulePriceServiceV1">
    <s:Body>

    </s:Body>

</s:Envelope>
```

Does anyone can help me figure it out?
Kind regards